# params hash changes after passing it in a module's class

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

My code looks something like this

```
class MyController

  def my_action
    #params hash gets passed here
      ...

    logger.debug "PARAMS >> #{params.inspect}" #first inspect

    @a = MyModule::MyClass.new(params).my_func #some operations done with the argument

    logger.debug "PARAMS >> #{params.inspect}" #second inspect

  end

end
```

My problem is, the params hash in the 'second inspect' is different from the one in the 'first inspect'. When the  params hash is passed in the class' initializer, some more key value pairs added to it, and when I do the 'second inspect' on params I find the same key value pairs in it too! How is this possible? I even tried passing a separate variable that contains the action's params hash, but in vain!

first inspect : `{"action"=>"report", "controller"=>"member/monitoring", "offset"=>"0"}`

second inspect : `{"new_key1"=>"new_val1", "action"=>"report", "controller"=>"member/monitoring","new_key2"=>"new_val2", "new_key3"=>"new_val3", "offset"=>"0"}`

The new_key* are added inside the class, but they turn up in the action's params hash too.

Comment: Can please add the output of `first inspect` and `second inspect` also. It would be helpful to understand. Or at least the difference.

Comment: Also if something really being changed, then that should be in the `MyModule::MyClass` line... so tell something about that also. What is it actually doing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Values passed as parameters to a method are by reference in Ruby, not by value. As such, they can be descructive and can change your hash. You can easily fix this by using `params.dup` as the argument to your `new` method.

Edit: As mu pointed out, it is more appropriate to actually let the `new` method itself do the `dup`, instead of duping before passing `params`.

Comment: It would be better if the MyModule::MyClass ctor did the dup'ing.